# Trying to build muParser: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream but no definition available

Tags: c++, macos, qt, gcc, qt-creator

Im trying to build muParser on the mac, it worked until I upgraded XCode to 4.4 which updated gcc. Now I get the following line of code generating the error which I don't understand:

```
mu::console() << _T(" \"") << val.GetAsString() << _T("\" ");

../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823:   instantiated from here
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823:   instantiated from here
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823:   instantiated from here
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp: In instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]':
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823:   instantiated from here
../muparser/src/muParserBase.cpp:1823: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
```

`mu::console()` is define as:

```
inline std::ostream& console()
{
  return std::cout;
}
```

`_T` is `#define _T(x) x`

and `GetAsString`

```
  const TString& GetAsString() const
  {
    return m_strTok;
  }
```

`TString` is a `std::string`

It is the call to GetAsString that causes the problem. Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Here is the Makefile generated by Qt Creator: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=NpXKqpLD

Answer (score 9):

Add these two lines to your .pro file and the error will go away:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64 += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_X86_64 = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64
```

Comment: What if I want my binaries to be compatible with Mac OS X 10.4?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are linking the wrong standard library or including the wrong C++ includes. You will want to make sure your include path c++ headers matches the standard library you are linking.

If you post your build file, I can help see if there is a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded to XCode 4.4.x, the Command Line Tools were removed. In XCode, I wend to XCode > Preferences, selected the Downloads tab, and re-downloaded "Command Line Tools" and then things started to work again. Maybe this will fix your problem too?