# C++: Running code (created in Linux) on Mac OS X, Qt 5.0

Tags: c++, linux, macos, qt

When I run project that was created in Linux I get error in the "std::cout<<..." line:

```
void Assert(bool condition, std::string message)
  {
    if(!condition)
     {
        std::cout<<"message"<<message<<std::endl;
        int s = 4/0;
     }
}
```

Error message:

```
/MainData.cpp:159: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream<_CharT,
_Traits>& std::operator<<(std::basic_ostream<_CharT, _Traits>&, const
std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = 
std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' but no definition available
```

include lines:

```
#include"iostream"
#include"vector"
#include "math.h"
#include"cstdlib"
#include "string"
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What type is `message`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz `message` is a string.

Comment: Show your #include lines.

Comment: @n.m. #include"iostream"
#include"vector"
#include "math.h"
#include"cstdlib"

Comment: I think you are missing `<string>`.  See my answer below.  BTW, if you could, edit your question above to include this detail about your `#include` lines, so its easier for everyone to follow, especially in case my 'answer' below misses the mark.

Comment: @JoeZ added <string>, same issue

Comment: Show much more of your code.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a *complete* program you can post?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch So the problem is described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748504/trying-to-build-muparser-error-explicit-instantiation-of-stdbasic-ostream-b), I should have added those two lines to my pro file after switching to mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears this is a MacOS specific quirk, solved by adding the compiler flag `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`.

Specifically (as the first link below states), add these two lines to your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64 += -mmacosx-version-min=10.7
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_X86_64 = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS_X86_64
```

Supporting links:

- [Trying to build muParser: error: explicit instantiation of 'std::basic_ostream but no definition available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748504/trying-to-build-muparser-error-explicit-instantiation-of-stdbasic-ostream-b)
- [Mex files on Mountain Lion: explicit instantiation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568925/mex-files-on-mountain-lion-explicit-instantiation-error)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. including <string> didn't help. Same error, same line.

Comment: Ok, my hunch was wrong.  But, some further research unearthed this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748504/trying-to-build-muparser-error-explicit-instantiation-of-stdbasic-ostream-b     Specifically, you need to add this to your compile flags: `-mmacosx-version-min=10.7`

Comment: More supporting docs from that research:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15568925/mex-files-on-mountain-lion-explicit-instantiation-error

Comment: Thanks, these worked for solving the error message, but I'm getting  new message "Executable doesn't exist" after building the project. I guess that is different topic, I will make some research about this. Could you post this as a separate answer, so I could choose it as the correct one.

Comment: I'll update this answer to include the punchline from the other links, replacing my earlier suggestion.